# CSS special classes, like ":-moz-placeholder"

Tags: css, sass, less, stylus

I've seen CSS styling along the following lines:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {...}
```

or

```
input:-moz-placeholder {...}
```

And they raise a few questions for me:

- What are these things called? (I'm having trouble googling them.)
- Is there a comprehensive list somewhere of which ones are supported by which browsers?
- Which meta-CSS languages (Sass, Less, Stylus, etc) have support for these, if any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing with one colon called pseudo-classes, it is used address different states of object (like :hover and ‘active).

Shot description and list can be found there: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses 
Description on w3.org: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes

The thing with 2 colons called pseudo-elements, it is used to autogenerate content or to style part of content like first letter of first line.

Description on w3.org: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements

There is lot of browser-specific extensions of this list through. That didn't documented in css3 standard.

You can find list for Mozilla's browsers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions in the section "Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes".

Can't find good list of Webkit pseudo-elements and -classes through.

Answer (score 3):

They're called vendor specific properties, and they typically are a vendors version of a CSS3 format.  Since CSS3 isn't a standard yet, technically any browser that implements them are implementing a vendor specific extension.

-moz mean Mozilla, aka firefox, etc..
-webkit means webkit based browsers, ie Safari, Chrome, Konqueror, etc..
-ms

See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific

Comment: I understand vendor specific properties (such as "-webkit-border-radius" etc.), I'm referring specifically to these pseudo-class-ish selectors for things like the html5 input attribute of input fields ("::-webkit-input-placeholder") which is matched at a class level and isn't a property. Vendor specific classes, perhaps?

Comment: @So8res - Well, they're vendor specific psuedo-classes, but I wouldn't expect to find much on that specific term, since most texts just refer to them as HTML5/CSS3 pseudo-classes.  The vendors that implement them just use vendor extensions until they've been finalized.